# Is there a way to add background-image to theme.json?

Tags: images, css, json, theme.json

I thought the following would work, but it doesn't. I can't find a firm confirmation if Gutenberg allows the following:

"styles": {
"color": {
"backgroundImage": "url('assets/images/hf_bg2.png')"
}

Is this allowed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Background image in theme.json is not yet supported

In your theme.json file, you can define a CSS class name for the element that you want to add the background image to. For example:

```
"styles": {
  "hf-bg": {
    "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
  }
}
```

In this example, we've defined a style called hf-bg that sets the backgroundColor property to white. You can then add custom CSS to your theme to apply a background image to this element. For example:

```
.hf-bg {
  background-image: url('assets/images/hf_bg2.png');
}
```

This CSS will apply a background image to any element with the class hf-bg. Make sure to adjust the URL to the location of your image file relative to your theme's root directory.

Answer (score 0):

Technically..... you can
but as @Oshik mentioned, its not really supported

Since 6.2, WordPress has added the support for custom css properties in theme.json

```json
{
    "version": 2,
    "$schema": "https://schemas.wp.org/wp/6.2/theme.json",
    "styles": {
        "css": ".my-custom-css { background: lime; }"
    }
}
```

This will output the css properties

```html
<style id="global-styles-inline-css">
   .my-custom-css { 
      background: lime; 
   }
</style>
```

Look out for the style tag with id `global-styles-inline-css`

To keep up to date with what's supported, you can view https://schemas.wp.org/wp/latest/theme.json

---

personal opinion... i'd rather do this in normal css than in the theme.json